# Why is the identity not considered when expanding a $2 \times 2$ matrix in the Pauli basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

I am aware of the expansion of a two dimensional matrix $M$ in Pauli basis  given by

$$ M = \sum_{\mu=0,1,2,3} c_\mu \sigma_\mu$$

with $\sigma_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\  0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, the Identity matrix and $\sigma_{1,2,3}$ the three Pauli matrices.

However, in this published [article on page-14, below equation 28](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5133), one finds the following:

*Parameterising the qubit operators as $ Q = a \cdot \hat{\sigma} $ , with $\hat{\sigma}$ the vector of Pauli matrices and $a$, a unit vector* (I have dropped the subscripts $i$ on $Q$ and $a$ here which merely labels the time in this case and is irrelevant here)

My question: Why is the Identity matrix not taken into account as per this article?

Comment: Presumably they are allowed to assume $Q$ to be traceless for whatever reason (possibly related to assuming that observables have mean 0?).

Comment: ... or "vector of Pauli matrices" includes the identity as $\sigma_0$.

Answer (score 0):

The set of $2\times 2$ complex matrices can be understood as a real vector space of dimension $2\times 2^2$, or equivalently, as a complex vector space of dimension $2^2$.

You can easily verify that a basis for the vector space is given by the Pauli matrices *and* the identity matrix. More precisely, we can write
$$\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb C) = \mathrm{span}_{\mathbb R}(\{I,iI,\sigma_x,i\sigma_x,\sigma_y,i\sigma_y,\sigma_z,i\sigma_z\}) 
= \mathrm{span}_{\mathbb C}(\{I,\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z\}),$$
where I'm denoting with $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb C)$ the space of $2\times2$ complex matrices.

You clearly need the identity in the basis, as $I$ cannot be written as a linear combination of Pauli matrices.